# Override React navigation SearchBar to add Segmented Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Is there a way to Override the header in react navigation with Search Bar and Segmented control using React navigation without writing a fully custom header? I want to use the inbuilt search component provided by react navigation but add a segmented control when search is tapped. Also want the native large title style in iOS.

React navigation has an option to specify Search Options which shows a SearchBar but I am not sure if I can override this functionality. Refer to screenshot below:

[image: Search with Segmented control]

Answer (score 1):

the best I could do was

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: () => {
                return <SegmentedControl style={{ width: 200, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                    values={['One', 'Two']}
                    selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                    onChange={(event) => setSelectedIndex(event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex)}
                />
            },
        });
    });
```

this replaces the small header title with a segmented control. header animations and search bar still work.

later edit: i just realized, this is the native behavior as well (you can check it on ios in the recents tab, on the call screen). the segements replace the small header title :)

[result video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRLta.gif)